# Voximplant scenario crashes

Tags: voximplant

Here's my Voximplant scenario:

```
val callSettings = CallSettings()
val array = mapOf("X-PARAMCUSTOM" to "test")
callSettings.extraHeaders = array
```

when I add these lines to my scenario, it crashes with the following error:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Can you explain why. Here's my code:

```
VoxEngine.addEventListener(AppEvents.CallAlerting, (e) => {
var  newCall = VoxEngine.callUser(
  e.destination,
  e.callerid,
  e.displayName,
  null,
  e.headers
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an object to the callUser() method, not just a list of properties:

```js
const  CallSettings = {
  username: 'user',
  callerid: e.callerid,
};
const  newCall = VoxEngine.callUser(CallSettings);
```

You can find more information in the Voximplant calls documentation here:
https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/calls/scenario